# CSS Element on the left of an Iframe

Tags: html, css

I currently have a css element on-top of an iframe, instead I need it to be on the same line, and I just can't figure it out.
[image: This is how it looks now.]

[image: How it should be, pardon, the horrid mockup.]

```
 <div class="tsk">
 <p>Words</p></div>
 </div>

.tsk{
 line-height:1.4em;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding:25px;
 width:30%;
 color:#FFF;
 background: rgba(75,123,365,.5);
 float: center;
 text-align:left;
 border-radius:50px 50px 0px 0px;
 }


 iframe{
 width:70%;
 height:500px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `float: left;` the `tsk` div and `float: right;` the `iframe`:

```
.tsk {
    line-height:1.4em;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding:2%;
    width:25%;
    color:#FFF;
    background: rgba(75, 123, 365, .5);
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    border-radius:50px 50px 0px 0px;
}
iframe {
    width:70%;
    height:500px;
    float: right;
}
```

You have one extra `</div>` in the html and you should remove it.

```
<div class="tsk">
    <p>Words</p>
</div>
<iframe src="#"></iframe>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

And after the iframe you should clear the floated divs.

Comment: That broken things, more than it fixed, to be honest.

Comment: That did that! Thanks.

Comment: Sort of, when I do multiples it just piles/ stacks, doesn't leave any spaces.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you update your question with the problem now?